# Sending path having spaces to batch file from c#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, batch-file

I have a application that executes a batch file from within the application. the batch file contains this

```
attrib %1 +h +r +s /s /d
pause
```

my code in c# application is

```
Process p = new Process();
string m=@"C:\Users\INDERJEET\Desktop\Antivirus works\Antivirus\Batchfiles\Testproject";
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\INDERJEET\Desktop\Antivirus works\Antivirus\Batchfiles\hide_2.bat";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = m;
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p.Start();
```

when ever i run this. it seems to only pick the path uptil C:\Users\INDERJEET\Desktop\Antivirus and not after that.. how to send the entire path to cmd.

Comment: You need use double quotes (`"`) around the path - `string m=@"""C:\Users\INDERJEET\Desktop\Antivirus works\Antivirus\Batchfiles\Testproject""";`

Comment: Even though i have put a pause statement in .bat file. it just comes up for a second and goes away. this happens when i put the double quotes around the path.

Comment: @Tim is there any other way to send the path?? or alernate  correction that would solve the problem. because the double quote method wasnt working. i tried the     p.StartInfo.Arguments =m.Replace(' ','%');    . doesnt work since % not the same path location.

Answer (score 1):

Try using double quote (`"`) around the path.  Since you're using a string literal, you'll need to escape the double quote with a second double quote (like this `""`):

```
string m = @"""C:\Users\INDERJEET\Desktop\Antivirus works\Antivirus\Batchfiles\Testproject""";
```

The result of the above code should pass the following parameter into your batch file:

```
"C:\Users\INDERJEET\Desktop\Antivirus works\Antivirus\Batchfiles\Testproject"
```

Comment: how can i check what it sends to my batch file? because the batch file closes immediately when it runs

Comment: @InderjeetSingh It sends exactly what you are telling to send. No magic in it.

Comment: @InderjeetSingh - If you want to see what was sent in, Echo it.

Comment: @ondrej Janacek. it isn't executing the command sing the file isn't being hidden. otherwise why would i ask that question..